# ViewModels in Repository

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have read that the repository layer should not deal with ViewModels because of separation of concerns and should instead deal only with Models. This is also true for the service layer (in my case this is where my business logic is). So then the controller is left to deal with the population of the ViewModels.

I have a Model Category:

```
public class Category
{

 public int ID { get; set; }

 public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }


 public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<CategoryName> CategoryNames{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel CategoryListViewModel used when displaying all Categories

```
public class CategoryListViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ParentName { get; set; }
    }
```

My view takes IEnumerable<...CategoryListViewModel>

This is how I populate the ViewModel from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            IEnumerable<CategoryListViewModel> model;
            List<CategoryListViewModel> list = new List<CategoryListViewModel>();
            IEnumerable<Category> categoryList = categoryService.GetAllCategoriesList(RouteData);

            foreach (var item in categoryList)
            {
                CategoryListViewModel temp = new CategoryListViewModel()
                {
                    ID = item.ID,
                    Name = categoryService.GetCategoryName(RouteData, item.ID)                    
                };
                if (item.ParentCategoryID != null)
                {
                    temp.ParentName = categoryService.GetCategoryName(RouteData, (int)item.ParentCategoryID);
                }
                list.Add(temp);
            }
            model = list;
            return View(model);
        }
```

My service methods:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategoriesList(RouteData data)
        {
            LanguageService languageService = new LanguageService();
            Languages langEnum = languageService.LanguageStringToEnum(languageService.DetermineSelectedLanguage(data));

            IEnumerable<Category> allCategories = repository.getAllCategoriesTest();            

            return allCategories;
        }

public string GetCategoryName(RouteData data, int categoryId)
        {
            LanguageService languageService = new LanguageService();
            Languages langEnum = languageService.LanguageStringToEnum(languageService.DetermineSelectedLanguage(data));
            return repository.GetCategoryName(langEnum, categoryId);
        }
```

And finally my repository methods:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> getAllCategoriesTest()
        {
            return db.Category.ToList();
        }


public string GetCategoryName(Languages lang, int categoryId)
        {
            return db.CategoryName.Where(cn => cn.CategoryID == categoryId && cn.Language == lang).Select(cn => cn.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

This approach looks very bad to me. My Controller is not thin anymore and I am running a lot of queries for something that simple.

If I allow ViewModels in my repository I get a much cleaner solution.

My Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(categoryService.GetAllCategories(RouteData));            
        }
```

Service method:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryListViewModel> GetAllCategories(RouteData data)
        {
            LanguageService languageService = new LanguageService();
            Languages langEnum = languageService.LanguageStringToEnum(languageService.DetermineSelectedLanguage(data));

            return repository.SelectAllCategories(langEnum);
        }
```

And repository method:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryListViewModel> SelectAllCategories(Languages lang)
        {                        
            var categories = db.Category.Include(c => c.CategoryNames).Select(names => new CategoryListViewModel
            {
                ID = names.ID,
                Name = names.CategoryNames.Where(cn => cn.Language == lang).Select(cn => cn.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                ParentName = db.CategoryName.Where(cn => cn.Language == lang && cn.CategoryID == names.ParentCategoryID)
                .Select(cn => cn.Name).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();            
            return categories;                             
        }
```

This approach, although violating separation of concerns seems to be "cleaner" to me.

My question is isn't the other approach more efficient in term of queries? Also is there any other way that this could be done so as not to write heavy controller methods and not execute that many queries? It seems to me that I am missing something.

Comment: Personally I use a [factory pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern). So every viewmodel has a viewmodel factory that creates it. This separates this creation logic from the controller logic, Controllers should be a routing component only.

Comment: Of course the other thing to bear in mind is a model is a domain level object. It does not need to map one to one with a table.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. This idea would move the creation of viewmodel outside of controller, this is true. Still, if I were to just move it I would still end up with "a lot" of code for something simple and would still execute what seems like unnecessarily many queries. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes. Build a SQL query and return a domain object. I'm guessing your using Entity Framework. TBH I hate entity framework and never use it. But I think you can write a stored proc and bind to this. The other option is to use a more flexible ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: Yes I am using Entity Framework. Do you mean creating a return type class (essentially the same as my ViewModel) and then building my ViewModel from that?

Comment: Entity Framework definitely has its flaws, but it still has a lot of merit too. For most things, EF is just fine. When it's not, you can employ stored procedures, user-defined functions, etc. directly via SQL. You can even easily integrate all this back into your context, so it's very seamless.

Comment: I mean EF tries to strongly bind your models to tables. This isn't always helpful. I often build models that are built from multiple tables data but I still use them like models. I think [@ChrisPratt](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0695435/) covers this quite well in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44927246/542251). A model is just a piece of data that comes from outside the controller. That doesn't have to be an EF context or a single database table. It can be a service and this service can send a more complete model that isn't tightly bound to a table, etc.

Comment: Depends on how you're trying to use it, I guess. An entity is merely an object representing a relational database table. If you realize this and accept it, then the way EF works makes perfect sense. The problem is that ASP.NET MVC tries to shoe-horn the entity as the Model of the application, and yeah, when you do that, the whole thing breaks down.

Answer (score 2):

First, bear in mind that even though it has "MVC" in the name, ASP.NET MVC only very loosely implements the MVC pattern. MVC tells you to have thin controllers because the Model is an active record, which handles *all* the business logic, including that around querying itself. This does not apply to ASP.NET MVC. There, your Model is actually a combination of your DAL, service layer, entity and one or more view models. This means the controller inevitably must do at least a little more work than a controller in something like Ruby on Rails, if only to wire all this stuff together.

As @Liam suggested in the comments above, your best bet is factories. That way, the controller does not actually own the logic for how to map an entity to a view model. You'll of course still need to actually call the factory in your controller, but the logic remains abstracted.

Also, a proper service layer should roll up logic that would otherwise be in your controller. If you need the localized name for the category, your service should have a method that returns all the categories with their localized name already. If you're having to hit your service multiple times, that's a clear indication that you haven't provided a necessary endpoint for your application. You may need to introduce a DTO to handle this data, since the entity class may not have the appropriate properties. You'd then have a factory that maps your DTO to a view model.

Finally, for what it's worth, your repository is completely unnecessary. Just have your service interact directly with your Entity Framework context. Having a repository buys you nothing but just an additional thing you have to maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I simply use a DTO instead of my viewmodel (in the second approach I mentioned)? I would then have an anonymous variable fetching the DTO via service and then mapping DTO to my viewmodel? I quite like this idea. The only thing that seems kinda weird it that, in this case my DTO and my viewmodel would be the same (look at the second approach I proposed). Isn't that unnecessary code duplication? Regarding the repository, I agree. I just wanted to separate business logic from data access.

Comment: Yes and no. On the surface, it looks like a duplicate class, but each is completely segregated. The view model is concerned with the needs of the view and could diverge over time based on that. Likewise, the DTO is concerned with the service and could diverge over time if that service endpoint needs to return additional data. The fact that they look similar at this point in time is inconsequential.